# Flutter Paint Canvas - Draw a line with gradient running from side of line to the other, not end to end

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-canvas

[image]

I have the x,y for both ends of this line on a canvas, how do I run a gradient from the line sides(as pic).

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(x,
            y),
        Offset(x,
            y),
        Paint()
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 4.0
          ..shader = ui.Gradient.linear( // What do I use here? 
          startOffset,
          endOffset,
         [
         color1,
         color2,
         ],
         ),);
```

Comment: is any solution find?

Comment: I drew lines of different thicknesses on top of each other and colored them to create a gradient that is not as smooth but you can't tell too much. I plan to solve this using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985577/how-do-you-calculate-the-x-y-points-of-all-corners-of-a-square-from-two-only-a-p with a geometry package - will update this if I find the time.