# How do you calculate the x,y points of all corners of a square from two only a pair of x,y points (see pic)

Tags: trigonometry, paint

[image]

I have the green x,y points, how would I get the missing red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate the two known points of 90° around their midpoint.

In pseudo code:

```
// Evaluate the midpoint from the coordinates of points a and b, 
h_x = (b_x - a_x) / 2;
h_y = (b_y - a_y) / 2;

m_x = a_x + h_x;
m_y = a_y + h_y;

// Apply a rotation of 90 degree around the midpoint to find c and d
c_x = m_x - h_y;
c_y = m_y + h_x;
d_x = m_x + h_y;
d_y = m_y - h_x;
```

---

This result can be formally derived in terms of homogeneous coordinates and transfomation matrices.

The midpoint **m**, expressed in homogeneous coordinates, can be calculated as

[image: \begin{align*}\mathbf{h}=\frac{1}{2}\(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\)&=\begin{pmatrix}h_x\\h_y\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0.5\cdot\(b_x-a_x\)\\0.5\cdot\(b_y-a_y\)\\1\end{pmatrix}\\\mathbf{m}=\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h}&=\begin{pmatrix}m_x\\m_y\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_x+h_x\\a_y+h_y\\1\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}]

To rotate a vector around the origin of an angle α, we apply a rotation matrix like

[image: R_{\alpha}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos{\alpha}&-\sin{\alpha}&0\\ \sin{\alpha}&\cos{\alpha}&0\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow\quad R_{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}]

If another center of rotation is needed (the midpoint, in our case), we need to translate from the original position to the origin, apply the rotation and translate back again. The translation matrices are

[image: T_{\mathbf{v}}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&v_x\\0&1&v_y\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow\quad T_{\mathbf{-m}}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-m_x\\0&1&-m_y\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix},\quad T_{\mathbf{m}}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&m_x\\0&1&m_y\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}]

The complete transformation can be expressed as

[image: \begin{align*}\mathbf{c}=M_{\mathbf{m},\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot \mathbf{b}&=T_{\mathbf{m}}\cdot R_{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot T_{\mathbf{-m}}\cdot\mathbf{b}\quad=T_{\mathbf{m}}\cdot R_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot T_{\mathbf{-m}}\cdot\mathbf{a}\\\mathbf{d}=M_{\mathbf{m},\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot \mathbf{a}&=T_{\mathbf{m}}\cdot R_{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot T_{\mathbf{-m}}\cdot\mathbf{a}\quad=T_{\mathbf{m}}\cdot R_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot T_{\mathbf{-m}}\cdot\mathbf{b}\\\end{align*}]

Where

[image: M_{\mathbf{m},\frac{\pi}{2}}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&m_x\\0&1&m_y\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-m_x\\0&1&-m_y\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&m_y+m_x\\1&0&-m_x+m_y\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}]

So that we can evaluate, let's say **d**, with

[image: \begin{align*}\mathbf{d}=M_{\mathbf{m},\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot\mathbf{a}=&\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&m_y+m_x\\1&0&-m_x+m_y\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a_x\\a_y\\1\end{pmatrix}\\=&\begin{pmatrix}-a_y+m_y+m_x\\a_x-m_x+m_y\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-a_y+a_y+h_y+a_x+h_x\\a_x-a_x-h_x+a_y+h_y\\1\\\end{pmatrix}\\=&\begin{pmatrix} m_x+h_y\\m_y-h_x\\1\\\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}]

Q.e.d.

Comment: I would add the note that a CCW 90° rotation of coordinates `(x, y)` is `(-y, x)` for reference.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thanks for the advise. I've edited the answer to add more details.